# How to extract numbers from a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of coordinates as follows

```
str='(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)'
```

I want to extract the values, but the parenthesis is getting hard to workaround. I tried the following:

```
str.split(",") which gives ['(707.027', '949.189)', '(598.919', '6.48649)']
str.split(",\(\)") which gives ['(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)']
```

Comment: try split on `[^\d.]+` or just `findall` with `[\d.]+`

Comment: is it always in this form? if so the first solution should work..if not then it wont

Comment: The findall works with [\d.]+. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given your string you could also use this more general purpose approach:

```
import re
s = '(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)'
nums = re.findall('\d*\.\d*',s)
nums #['707.027', '949.189', '598.919', '6.48649']
```

this strips out all the floats from any string..then you can do whatever you want with them, i.e. put them into tuples:

```
coords = list(zip(nums[::2],nums[1::2]))
coords #[('707.027', '949.189'), ('598.919', '6.48649')]
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but you probably want to convert those strings to floats.

Comment: then either map or convert to float once they're extracted...the purpose of this approach was to be more general purpose than simply evaluating the string which just so happens to be in a format that allows that

Answer (score 3):

Your string is a valid Python literal, so try [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)'
>>> literal_eval(s)
((707.027, 949.189), (598.919, 6.48649))
```

This parses `s` as Python code and evaluates it (safely, as a literal value), resulting in a tuple of tuples.

Comment: Cool! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

python Built-in function`eval` can do it, it parse a string into code.

```py
>>> s = '(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)'
>>> eval(s)
((707.027, 949.189), (598.919, 6.48649))
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use an `eval` in this case, that's generally not a safe way of dealing with this type of data, especially if the string you're trying to interpret isn't in your code or entered by yourself.

Here's a solution with regex, as you requested:

```
import re

subject = '(707.027,949.189),(598.919,6.48649)'
match = re.search(r"\(([\d.]+),([\d.]+)\),\(([\d.]+),([\d.]+)\)", subject)

numbers = []
p1, p2 = tuple(), tuple()
if match:
    numbers = [float(match.group(n)) for n in range(1, 5)]
    # or
    p1 = (float(match.group(1)), float(match.group(2)))
    p2 = (float(match.group(3)), float(match.group(4)))

print(numbers, p1, p2)
```